# What are the alternatives to Stack Overflow for opinion based questions?

Tags: discussion

One of my questions where I want to hear people's opinions was closed and marked as opinion based. I want to have an opinion based answer, to an opinion based question.

Where should I go instead of Stack Overflow?

Comment: The chats are a viable alternative.

Comment: @Trilarion:  Not in my experience.  I asked question in chat, exactly because it wasn't a good fit for a SO/SE question, and was merely given a list of SE sites that nominally fit the question domain.

Comment: @user1071847 Sorry to hear that people in chat were not very useful for you.  Still at least your question in chat got not closed. I would ask it again with the added notion that you are not looking for SE sites to fit your question but want to have opinion based answers in chat. That should make it clear to the readers that your question belongs to chat. If that doesn't help, what about reddit? It's much more relaxed with the rules and usually quite high quality too.

Comment: @Trilarion:  So you're saying that questions that are too broad/asking opinions are OK in chat?

Comment: I was also thinking about reddit but sometimes it seems overflowing with low-quality posts.

Comment: @user1071847 Yes, I think they are OK in chat.

Comment: Reddit, facebook, instagram, tiktok, IRC, MsnMessenger, ICQ

Comment: I think the problem with this question is that it's ironically _opinionated_. Haha! :-)
Maybe you need to save your opinions to a file on your hard drive? That's what I do.

Answer (score 5):

There are still traditional forums and other programming sites on the Internet.

Stack Exchange sites are a poor fit for such questions - though the [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) may accommodate such questions.