# Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I understand the pollution caused by too *broad questions* in a site trying to solve immediate and practical programming problems.
However, I also must admit that these kind of *questions* (and respective answers) are the ones I most learned from.

Actually, if I have to know *how to format a date*, I usually go to the documentation of the library.
Human support deserves parsimonious use, i.e. to questions with no exact answer or when some degree of wisdom is needed.

With all these points in mind, is there, or could be there, a place to ask open-ended questions?

Some context: there are questions that are not exactly specific, and are also not exactly open-ended. Are they condemned to stay in limbo? By now, the way Stack Overflow is, I think much wheat is being cut with the chaff.

Comment: Now the semi-dups are appearing at the left list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144

Comment: [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) (at least some anyway)

Comment: I found another semi-dup, but I think my question worded as is can be useful to someone. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252444/feature-request-opinon-based-site-for-stack-overflow?rq=1

Comment: It has been done before:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144

Comment: "There are questions that are not exactly specific, and are also not exactly open-ended." Sounds like a contradiction to me. Where white is also black, simultaneously `:P` If a question is one, how could it also be the other?

Comment: @Cupcake If a thing is not black, it can also be not white.

Comment: 50 tons of Gray is at the shelves to do not let me lie. :)

Comment: Do note that if you get a response that’s “a one line link to a tutorial”, you would be justified in flagging it as “not an answer”.

Comment: Isn't http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ the kind of site you're willing to have?

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Isn't it specifically for research or improvement oriented questions? I don't know

Comment: @N0062eclipse Anyway - you could try to dig http://area51.stackexchange.com/ site proposals to find something suitable or make yor own proposal. If community support it - you will get your own brand new site

Comment: O.M.G. Does nobody search Meta at all? @InfiniteRecursion wasn't there another question like this last night?

Comment: Oh and there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com If you are new to some technology you can write some code and ask community tech gurus to review it there.

Comment: @Cupcake [Yes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267168/best-way-to-help-brand-new-programmers#comment69595_267168), as [Makoto said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267168/best-way-to-help-brand-new-programmers#comment69600_267168), these questions are frequent on Meta :-(

Comment: @Cupcake any mechanism to merge similar questions? :)

Comment: Related: [meta-tags:split-stack-overflow], [Should Stack Overflow have a forum where users can talk about anything they want?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254466/456814), [Is there a place on Stack Exchange for programming discussions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266834/456814), [Add 'related' forums for questions that don't belong here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254563/456814), [Stack Overflow Academy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72987/stack-overflow-academy?referrer=bFkThEZ9P7sjquHM9dKpFQ2).

Comment: @Cupcake Whoa. What happened there? Can you send a comment to a user on Meta who's not already in on the conversation? Just curious, as I don't see a comment from InfiniteRecursion before yours.

Comment: I summoned Infinite Recursion using my magical high-rep user Cupcake powers, @MikeM. Joking(?) aside, you can ping anyone who has edited a post. It's explained in some Meta or [meta.se] question somewhere.

Comment: @MikeM. [here are the reply explanations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/163250). It needs to be updated though to explain that anyone who closes or reopens a question can't be pinged this way, it only works on edits, as far as I know.

Comment: Related: [meta-tag:split-stack-overflow].

Comment: See [Can you add a separate discussion site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32769), [What about those subjective questions -- is there a place for them?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200285), [Where can I discuss?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215864), [Community for subjective and possibly open-ended questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225487), and [Where can I find interesting programming discussions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13198), and then the master [The fourth place: polling, recommendations, and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383)

Comment: And then see what happened when it was tried: [Adding discipline to programmers.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65437)

Comment: This reference is also helpful:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/175248

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov wow. Just... wow. **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/165773) -> [Are you still confused about what Programmers is for?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5654/31260)**

Comment: Not a Stack Exchange site, but http://www.quora.com/ supports these kinds of questions.

Comment: see also: [What are the alternatives to Stack Overflow for opinion based questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251960/what-are-the-alternatives-to-stack-overflow-for-opinion-based-questions)

Comment: What ever happened to notconstructive.com?

Comment: Quora doesn't really limit you, so you could ask technical questions there. People do. I fully agree that, sadly, SE sites have become havens for the most pedantic people. I mean, if you have a question, I dare you to try to find the matching community and ask it. It'll be off-topic, too broad, too narrow, opinionated, etc.. It is extremely discouraging, which is why I don't bother asking anything on these sites anymore. If I see something I can help answer, I do, but as far asking - why put myself through that? And the negative votes have an emotional feel to them, even if not significant.

Comment: @dyasta "And the negative votes have an emotional feel to them, even if not significant." Do you mean negative votes are not signifcant, or emotions are not significant, or the amount of emotional feel in this case is not significant, or do you mean something else. A sincere question, not trying to be pedantic.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There are three types of broad questions that you can ask on SE site that you can't ask on Stack Overflow.

1. Code review questions for code that works.  That is covered on
   [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
2. Conceptual questions.  That is covered on [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*
3. Workplace questions.  That is covered on [workplace.stackexchange.com](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

These might not be the broad questions you want to ask, but there is a place for them.

---

*This site was previously named "Programmers".

Comment: And yet on each of those sites there is still a limit to how broad questions can be.  Questions like the examples the OP gave are not only not covered by any of those three topics (the *topic* of the question is in fact correct for SO), but also still way too broad for *any* site, even if the topic were to be a match for them.

Comment: @Servy - I agree Servy, that is why I added the last line.  Iff the OP does not know about these sites, I expect they will be of use to him.

Comment: @Hogan - `Programmers` site is pretty strict as well.  They do not want opinion-based answers either.  In my (not so humble) opinion *conceptual questions* can be rarely answered with with just hard facts.

Comment: @PM77-1 - Times change as do expectations.  Programmers is much harsher now than they were at the time.

Comment: What about design questions?  These questions are sometimes flagged as open-ended or subjective.  While they are not quite as crisp and objective as questions about problems with some tool, they are not quite invitations to wide open discussion either.  Almost all design questions admit more than one possible answer, and all most all design principles have exceptional cases where they should be overlooked.

Comment: @WalterMitty - You can try programmers or codereview -- a design document might be interesting to the code review guys, you could also go to the meta of those sites and ask there first if you don't want to post a question that gets closed.

Comment: For myself, I am primarily interested in answering database design questions.  These questions usually crop up in DBA or SE.  Some of the best questions, IMO, get downvoted or closed as too broad or subjective.  Also, questions that are "cloaked duplicates" never get flagged as such because, on the surface, they look completely different.

Comment: I asked a conceptual question on software engineering, and I got deleted a few hours later.

Comment: @A.Rashad -- It is hard to respond to this comment without knowing what you asked, there could be many reasons it was closed.

Comment: It was a general inquiry about the existence of a language imposing TDD as part of its syntax, so that you are to write test cases along with implementation of the method as part of a method declaration. It was somehow considered a language specific question and was deleted in less than 24 hours since I wrote it

Comment: @A.Rashad -- you wanted to know if such a thing existed?  That isn't a conceptual question it is a research question.  Research questions and lists (What are the top 10...?) are not allowed on any site (as far as I know).

Comment: Is there a location one can ask questions about where to find tools or code of a general category that cannot be easily found by search engine?

Comment: Also worth mentioning is the [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Stackoverflow is full of mere debugging questions. I think good open-ended questions about a concept or a code pattern would be much more valuable and more likely to help other developers than ultra specific debugging questions that helps two people at most (the one who asked that solves his problem and gets 2 points and the one who answered that gets 15 points).

Comment: This post is incomplete and encourages moving broad, off-topic questions to other network sites. This is a [real](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777) [problem](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7182). More information is necessary to make this a valuable answer. Links to each network site's [how to ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) pages is a step forward. How about theoretical/conceptual computer science questions? CS SE is more appropriate than SWE SE.

Comment: @ggorlen -- Feel free to edit the answer -- I'm excited to see your improvements.  You do know I wrote this about 6 years ago?  Some things might have changed.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks for responding and inviting me to edit, but I think my edits would change the intent too much. I know things have changed in 6 years but I have to address  the post as it is now since the question is heavily linked-to, canonical and still relevant.

Comment: @ggorlen -- ok but I'm not sure exactly how to address your issues -- if you ant private email / chat me with your suggestion and I'll put it in if it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 65):

There are lots of places where you can ask open-ended questions - more traditional forums, for example.

However, none of these places are Stack Exchange sites.

We focus on Questions and Answers - not discussions. That's what drove (and is still driving) the design decisions behind the site and how it works.

Coercing this format into a discussion platform will hurt this goal.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Answer (score 31):

Quora is pretty neat, and you don't spend 80% of your time arguing why your question is acceptable for the site.

Edit: this is not true anymore. Quora sucks, not because of their moderation policy, but because they went overboard on monetization and are no longer really a questions/answer platform.

Comment: At last! An actual answer that isn't "no"!

Comment: The downside to Quora is the answers are pretty much never direct. Then you do get into arguments about why the other person's credentials doesn't mean that they're right.

Comment: With the removal of question descriptions I would say Quora no longer fits this description.

Comment: Quora is a spam magnet when you need a recommendation. For general questions, seems ok

Comment: God, i hate quora, but love the gist of your answer.

Comment: In my experince, Quora is (still?) good because there are some very good authors there. However, since they limited the whole question to just the subject line, you really cannot ask any complex questions there anymore. Some could argue that it's good for open endedness factor, but for me, the quality of Quora is going down. I think there would be space for Quora with stackexchange logic (reputation needed to do some stuff, ability to ask complex questions, ability to edit questions and answers with high enough reputation). The hard part is bootstrapping it without trolls and crap.

Comment: If stackoverflow / stackexchange should copy one feature from Quora, it would be having some kind of automatic smart search / AI that *suggests* interesting questions and answers to read.  Of course, they need to do lots of profiling to be successful in this. I think this is the only part of Quora where they're really good.

Comment: "Edit" does not belong in an answer (that is what the edit history is for). Instead, make the answer appear as if it was written today. For instance, by converting the first paragraph/sentence to paste tense (as a side effect, it would also tell a story about the rise and fall of Quora).

Answer (score 15):

**["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out.. C'est la vie.."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)**

> 3 years ago, a Stack Exchange site called [Not Programming Related](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) came out of [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the Stack Exchange staging zone. NPR was supposed to be a site where questions that were too subjective / broad for Stack Overflow would find a new home. The site was greeted with enthusiasm, and in theory it looked like a perfect solution: Stack Overflow would remain as laser sharp focused as possible, and NPR would host all those exciting and sometimes helpful (but not really *answerable*) questions.
>
> However, as it usually happens, theory and practice are two entirely different beasts. NPR's promise proved extremely attractive to people who were more interested in posting joke answers, or just repeating earlier answers, or posting outright crap ([Do you fart in the cubicle?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49548/do-you-fart-in-the-cubicle)). It didn't take long for everyone to realize that the site was not working, and most people just didn't bother with it. Here's what [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/programmers.stackexchange.com#!traffic) tells us for the first year of NPR's existence:
>
> [image]
>
> Tons and tons of people visited the site after it went public, but very few decided to stick around. For over a year, the site experienced no growth to speak of. And even fewer people contributed worthwhile content. Turns out that while everyone *loves* those questions, very few are *actually* willing to spend any time to answer them (seriously), and maintain and moderate them...
>
> #### Further reading
>
> - [What is the history behind the site scope change from NPR to “conceptual questions about software development”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3412/25936)
> - [Adding discipline to programmers.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65437/162704)
> - [Should Programmers.SE exist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153082/162704)

Comment: Exactly a site with the opposite title is requested by OP: Programming *Related* (as SO is too strict Programming *Only*)

Answer (score 11):

So let's think about this for a minute.  What is it that you're trying to glean from the Stack Exchange network?

Note that I'm not *trying* to sound condescending, but I will be breaking your question down a bit.

> Can we have a learning/brainstorming/discussions (basic newbie questions) site?

This sort of site seems orthogonal to the model that Stack Exchange is [trying to promote](https://stackexchange.com/tour).

> This site is all about **getting answers**. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

It also depends on the nature of the community as well; [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (to a lesser extent) all cover some piece of the spectrum that you're after, but they do so in such a way that wide-open discussion is less favored as opposed to more verifiable, concrete answers.

As to your point of answers providing detailed information (i.e. why this is a good approach), or lack thereof, this is where votes come in.  A user can upvote an answer that they feel is specifically useful to others, and downvote those that aren't.  For the most part, when I do answer a question, I try not to just provide a blob of code and assume that the asker is smart enough to understand what the snippet is doing; I'd try to break it down.  If you see answers that aren't useful, **don't be afraid to downvote them**; that's even what the tooltip says.

> This will reduce the number of possible duplicates as most users try to find code specific answers as compared to concept dependent answers.

I don't believe this.  First, I'm not sure I see duplicates as much of a problem anymore, thanks to binding votes for gold tag holders; second, the applicability of the answer depends on the problem being addressed.  If it's an algorithm that would efficiently search a two-dimensional array for the highest value, then code-oriented answers may actively do more harm than good.

> Community rules on SO are strict and still users post very silly questions (even I have when trying to understand a new concept).

Yes.  The community *is* strict.  So strict, that there are some times in which I've felt it a bit too unforgiving.  That's actually a good thing, as this keeps the quality of questions and answers high.  (And we still get our share of poor questions.)

I don't see how a brainstorming site would alleviate the strictness, either.  You have to do *something* to prevent people from asking how they could build a forum (obviously a sizable undertaking), or brainstorming about their next awesome MMO*.

> Have this site specifically for concept oriented, but code supported questions rather than code oriented questions.

Not having code in a question is not *necessarily* bad.  Discussing abstract concepts...well, that probably *is*.  But depending on the concept being discussed, an audience could be found at Programmers.

> Site providing learning opportunities through discussions (please don't say "refer to the documentation").

So this is where it kind of comes apart for me.  I can appreciate and respect that collaboration and discussion with those who know more can further one's knowledge greatly.  I'm a private CS tutor, and this is pretty much what I do for a few hours on a weekend.

But, in my experience, both as a professional developer, a tutor, and a Stack Overflow addict back in my Junior year of college, you can't just learn from a website.

## You have to *try* stuff.

Don't be afraid to break things.  And yes, there are going to be times in which the documentation is your best friend, since no one else is going to bother reading the code or understanding the problem space you're in.

No site can supplement actual hard experimentation and self-discovery.

<sup>*: Reminds me of my college days; I had a buddy that raved on and on and on about it.  He never did make his MMO, which is kind of a pity.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Questions as broad and open ended as you are describing would not be on topic anywhere on the network.

Comment: Not much explicative.

Comment: @davips What else is there to say.  You asked where they're acceptable.  The answer is nowhere.  Why waste your time saying anything more than that.

Comment: They are however acceptable on non-SE site, mailing-lists and code-review sites.

Comment: Several sites on the Stack Exchange Network have a [soft-question](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsoft-question%5D) tag for less-specific questions. I often see this tag on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question).

Comment: @AndersonGreen Yes, as a lot of people have said, some sites are less restrictive than others, but *none* of the sites allow the types of questions that were asked about.