# How can I ask about Java 8 tips and traps without running into "closed as primarily opinion based"?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask for people's experiences with the new Java 8 language features; specifically, this question:

> What are some non-obvious usages and what are the 'gotchas' of the new language features in Java 8?

But I think it will be closed as "primarily opinion based".  And certainly I guess in some ways, one person's "gotcha" is another person's "completely obvious implementation".  I can also see how some people might also see this question as an "opinion poll" or something like that.

The reason I want to ask the question is because I searched for it and expected it to already have been asked (maybe it has and it's been deleted as inappropriate).  I searched for this question because I wanted some early heads-up on potential pain-points to avoid or non-obvious possibilities enabled by the new features - and I'm positive the Stack Overflow community already knows some of the answers.

I was thinking about asking that people provide one tip or gotcha per answer and the community would vote up the answers they thought were worth knowing about.

Is this question a candidate for using the community wiki thing?  Or is the question just not worth asking?  If it is worth asking - how to structure it so that it won't get closed and will actually be be useful?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Comment: I would personally close it as overly broad, not "opinion based".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Feature request: Opinon-based site for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252444/feature-request-opinon-based-site-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: You should find a chatroom or a discussion forum in which to have this discussion. Well done for asking first, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - yeah, but then it would devolve into the useless opinionising, flaming and trash-talking that those types of forums are prone to.  It's a bit of a catch-22: the reasons* why I would want to ask this type of question here are are the same reasons why it would be closed.  And just so we're clear, the answers to this question have clarified my own understanding of SO. If those are the only two options - I prefer how SO works now.

(*)  - strong cultural norms of high-signal content enforced by strict moderation.

Comment: @Shorn: I guess you just have to bear in mind that this is a Q&A repository rather than a discussion board *shrug*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you write a question that will take into account the implementation of something, not just a general, very open-ended question like the one you mention. That question will get closed as too broad.

Provide guidelines to what you want to achieve so that the answer can focus on that and be helpful to other people looking for similar issues or implementations with Java 8. If you actually got a application or some code to write in Java 8, that's even better than trying to making it up for the sole purpose of asking a question.

Something along the lines of

> I want to implement/write this application/do this in Java 8. I've got to this point and is there any new features,
>   compared to 7 (or 6), that I can use that will make it easier? Any
>   pitfalls to avoid while doing this with 8?

This is just an example that isn't even that great but, IMO, should not be closed if you provide enough informations to what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah - I guess that does answer my query of how to ask the question and not get closed - but I don't think I will do that.  I think based on the downvote/feedback so far (and looking into the possible duplicate link) that this is a question that the SO community doesn't really want asked (fair enough too - I neither agree nor disagree).