# Are we supposed to speak like robots when asking questions or are we allowed to be human?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, signatures

I posted a question earlier today about changing grid sizes.

Here is the body of the question - [Having problems trying to resize gridworld grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696956/having-problems-trying-to-resize-gridworld-grid)

> So I basically want to resize the grid in gridworld the default 10x10 to whatever I want I've been testing it with 15x15 just to see if it works but I can't seem to figure this out and other sources on the internet say that what I'm doing should work.

(Creating small game for project) However, my question was rejected due to "***Several of those things are not code***" Here are some examples of what was crossed out and what was proposed. Although first I would like to add, my code was blocked off using Ctrl+K I've asked questions before all very similar to this and have never had a problem. I ATTEMPTED my problem which is something a lot of people don't do and I had a clear and specific problem. Nothing crazy abstract.

**Anything in () is what was crossed out or edited**

"(So) I (basically) want to resize the grid in (gridworld the) default (10x10 to) whatever I want I've been testing it with (15x15 just) to see if it works but I can't seem to figure this out and other sources on the internet say that what I'm doing should work.

(this) class is where I resize the grid"

*Insert code for Class A here*

"This class is the runner for the actor"

*Insert Code for Class B here*

"(Any help is appreciated, thanks.)"  <--- Am I not allowed to be polite and say thanks?!

In the end my question is. How are we supposed to speak? In my opinion people that are very strict like this create an unfriendly environment. We are here to learn and are looking for friendly community help. Speaking like automatons isn't to friendly to me.

Comment: Speak however you would like. This seems to be the work of an over-zealous editor and I have seen quite a lot of that lately.

Comment: Is there a way to get the downvotes removed? and possibly the question rolled back?

Comment: Regarding the "thanks" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts So no, no "thanks".

Comment: The downvotes are not likely the result of the edit, they are likely the result of not asking the question thoroughly. I just posted the text of your post and it is a run-on sentence that is not very clear.

Comment: Link to the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696956/having-problems-trying-to-resize-gridworld-grid

Comment: @Adamc23: There's no edit history on that question.  If someone other than you had edited it, there should be.

Comment: I have a notification for a link to suggested edits for the question and it shows the suggested edits, the user "war10ck" and Approve

Comment: Link to the suggested edit, then?

Comment: I would indeed significantly edit that post. Not so much to to make you sound like a robot, but to fix several obvious issues.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: The question was cleaned up to be more concise and readable. Questions are meant to be usable for more than just the OP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4828166

Comment: I understand @MartijnPieters, but even the cleaning left something to be desired.

Comment: I agree that questions are meant to be concise but I felt that there was no ambiguity in the question, sure maybe I forgot a period. But other than that It's not like I speak German and am going for broken English It's not too wordy.

Comment: If the only thing to edit is removing "Thanks" then it is hardly worth editing. But, if there are other fixes to be made, then often it will go too

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I found it a little hard to parse how the post was edited; it looks like it was a suggested edit and it was rejected, the actual post has not had such an edit applied.

Comment: Generally we're not editing to make you feel stupid or to be an ass @Adamc23. See it as us helping you out for free to improve your content. To make it more clear and concise so you get the answers you want/need and it's of lasting value to all the peoples of the intarwebz.

Comment: @Adamc23: That link says that the *edit* was rejected.  "Several of these things are not code" is the reason given by the mod who rejected it.  (The would-be editor was using backticks for emphasis, when they are meant for code and other verbatim input/output only.)

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Now that I've seen the actual edit, there is indeed much to be desired about it still. Removing 'So' and 'basically' was spot on, then it fell apart by using code formatting where it wasn't needed.

Comment: @cHao Okay that makes much more sense, still though not trying to be an ass but is it really that BADly asked? I mean some people post some bull on here like "Help me write this by xp.m." I thought my question was simple and clear. What should I do next time so this doesn't happen again?

Comment: @Louis: The OP got confused over the suggested edit rejection reason from Minitech.

Comment: Yeah @MartijnPieters - it was a mess all the way around.

Comment: To clarify, the suggested edit was rejected because the editor changed things like 10x10 to `10x10`, as though they were code, but they are not.

Comment: @Adamc23: Yeah, the text part is a bit of a rambly mess.  I'd at least use decent grammar and split it up into actual sentences.

Comment: @Adamc23: Look at it this way: someone cared enough about your question to try and improve it. Question that contain `Help me write this by xp.m` often don't get even that courtesy and are instead just closed.

Comment: One thing that you can do @Adamc23 is to use sentences with punctuation. Those little divisions help to make your issue and question well-defined.

Comment: Okay so I've revised my question, are there other suggestions now that I have corrected it? I mean still no one has even offered an answer or suggestion.

Comment: @Adamc23: (1) "Having problems" is even less descriptive than "doesn't work" -- and i hadn't even considered that *possible* til now.  What problems are you having?  What is happening that shouldn't?  What isn't happening that should?  The question needs to contain this info.

Comment: You can always rollback to your own version if you think it's better.

Comment: I think it's just time to scrap the question, I will try again at another time or just ask a friend. I will consider all of the suggestions next time I write a question.

Comment: Why did you scrap it? Folks were starting to vote to reopen the question because you had made several improvements.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Where do you see people voting to reopen the question? (Never experienced this before) Also because I figure I can just mess around with it more on my system and If I still have problems I'll come back to try and get an answer. I was getting nothing but downvoted so I figured it obviously was horribly asked and should go.

Comment: When a question is closed the link at the bottom of the question goes from 'close' to 'reopen'.

Comment: Is there a way to bring back a recently deleted question? Or?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83677/recover-an-accidently-deleted-post

Comment: @JayBlanchard Done

Comment: It has at least one re-open vote so it will get looked at by others who can vote to re-open. OAN - the downvotes may go away if the question is re-opened and folks can see that it is not a well formed question.

Comment: I still can't find where is shows that there are re-open votes. All I see is [On Hold] next to the title. I CTRL+f for "open" "reopen" and "re-open" Can others only see it since I shouldn't be able to vote to re-open my own question?

Comment: I think that is the case @Adamc23 but I can see those links, just below the tags, in a question I had closed some time back. That question was upvoted though.

Comment: It has 2 reopen votes now. It also has a comment that may be very helpful to you. Stay with it and you'll probably get your problem solved. (Deleted questions that get downvoted is never a good idea. Always put in the work to make them better.)

Comment: @KateGregory How many votes are required to re-open a question? Also am currently working on the comment now.

Comment: @Adamc23 5, same as to close. You can't see the links or the count unless you have enough rep to vote, so just hang patient and see what happens. Watch for comments that ask you questions, and edit the question to add that information.

Comment: @KateGregory The comment has already solved my problem but I probably won't be able to give credit, I have doubts that it will hit 5.

Comment: Regarding a signature and saying thanks, these things may be *nice*, but they don't actually add any value to the question itself, and are thus more distracting than actually helpful. Most people would prefer you leave it out, and will often edit it out for you. This is a Question and Answer site, it focuses on those things. We don't want a pleasant conversation, we just want clearly stated questions, and clearly stated answers. Everything else is just unnecessary cruft.

Comment: @Adamc23 You find signatures to be highly entertaining?  Really?  Most people are here because they find programming questions interesting.  *That* is what is entertaining to them.  Having to read through "Any help is appreciated, thanks." is what is boring and a waste of time.

Comment: @Adamc23 [main] is very much not a venue for socializing or discussion. In fact, it was created with the express purpose of [snuffing out discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254466/456814), with extreme prejudice. If you want to have an actual conversation, I recommend that you seek out [**an actual forum**](http://blog.codinghorror.com/civilized-discourse-construction-kit/) for that, not [main].

Comment: @Servy It was meant in no literal way, just joking around.

Comment: @Cupcake I was not trying to be derogatory, or to denounce anything I was just trying to end this parade of comments. I'm not angry at anyone or anything it was a sentiment of humor. In fact I'm glad I posted here today because it's fixed a way that I've type questions and responses. In no way did I mean to cause offense to anyone or anything.

Comment: @Adamc23 **Mindless soul-less robots do not appreciate your humor**. j/k! `;) <3 <3 <3`

Comment: see also: [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

First, your post was not rejected. It is, as I type, 4/5ths of the way to being put on hold so it can be improved. The improvements it needs are not for you to sound more like a robot. I often edit out chattiness in questions just to make them shorter - a person who knows how to solve your problem doesn't need to read all the context about how much a solution means to you - but that's not what's wrong with yours. You basically say:

> I want 10x10 but I was testing with 15x15 and anyway here's my code.

What is the **question**? What is the **problem**? Does your code not even compile? Does it blow up when it runs? Does it run fine, but the grid is the wrong size? Or can't be resized? Or the data in it doesn't look right? **You don't tell us**. And that means until you do, nobody can really answer. Sure, people could write up some random stuff related to what you appear to be doing, but it will only be a matter of luck if that helps you.

Please, edit your question to be a question and to explain what help you need. Then you will get the help you need.

On the matter of "tone" and of editing chit-chat out of posts, I have [an answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216604/147247) that may apply.

Comment: This is the thing I find most about new users: they don't ask a question. They post a problem, but no question to go along with it. And the implied "why doesn't this work?" is not good enough.

Comment: And they think SO is a helpdesk. It's not.

Answer (score 11):

*You* are not required to be a robot. However the legion of editors out there is indistinguishable from one. The protection against that is to make sure your question is clear and complete from the start so that nobody feels compelled to edit it.

Regarding the "thanks" at the end of the question, that goes back to an early philosophy for SO - anything that isn't part of the actual question is noise, and noise is actively harmful to the site. Jeff in particular was adamant that if that cruft were to accumulate it would imperil the long term viability of the site. He even put in code to remove what it could detect from the question before it was posted. I'm not sure if that code still exists today or not. Personally I think he took the philosophy way too far, but you can still see it in action today.

Comment: Interesting.  I've learned something new about how to write good SO questions.  Is it ok to say 'thanks' in the comments?  :-)

Comment: @MikeofSST, saying "thanks" in the comments is discouraged but not disallowed (yet). You might have noticed a question that's locked, and the text explaining the lock says it's to prevent "thanks" comments among other things.

Comment: @MikeofSST However there is a flag that can be raised against comments "Too chatty"