# What's so wrong with thanking people?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, signatures

So I've just been going through the suggested edit queue and it was just full of one guy removing the "thanks" from the bottom of all the posts.

Is this really necessary? What are your views on this?

**The edits in question**

- [edit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4847976)
- [edit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4847972)
- [edit 3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4847971)

*All* of them were approved by the way.

Comment: It's noise, distracting from the actual question. **Thousands** of people read these questions, not just those that answer the question. The OP gets to say 'thanks' by accepting a most helpful answer, in any case, so the social courtesy is not needed.

Comment: However, if this is *all* that the editor does, ignoring other glaring errors, then the suggested edits should be declined as 'too minor'.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that all of the linked edits were on posts that should be closed so there's no need for them to be edited just to take out the "Thanks".

Comment: Related MSE FAQ post: [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255157/are-we-supposed-to-speak-like-robots-when-asking-questions-or-are-we-allowed-to

Comment: It's annoying as much as "Good morning guys," is. (Not to mention that it's not necessarily right, since it [could be night somewhere else in the planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth's_rotation)).

Comment: [*"This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)