# Why is thanking discouraged in comments?

Tags: discussion, support

I would like to know why the community doesn't like this to happen. can someone enlighten me ?

A related (or same) question is:
Is there perhaps another way of letting users know I appreciate their help. (When someone is trying to help is doesn't automatically mean they provide the right answer)

Comment: Upvote. That's how you express that a post is helpful. Remember though, your votes should be for a post, and not for an individual.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I got the impression that the OP is talking about a case where an upvote is not warranted but the OP nonetheless appreciates the attempt at helping. I'd rather not see upvotes be awarded for effort.

Comment: Related (on Meta Stack Exchange): [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180/162704)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I agree that it is up to them. It won't change my opinion that giving an upvote for anything else than a technically correct answer is not the right way to vote. Just like I don't think it is okay to downvote because the voter does not like the OP's avatar, or thinks the OP's name is ridiculous, or because it is 5pm and 5pm is downvote time.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker And HCP is saying that he wants to thank someone for providing a post that *they feel isn't useful, and thus don't think should be upvoted*.  Saying that all thanks should be expressed in the form of upvotes, when upvotes are not appropriate in all contexts where someone wishes to thank someone, isn't right.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker And even in the event that the OP isn't specifically referring to that situation (although it sounds to me like he is) it still is entirely sensible for that situation to exist.  Saying that anytime you want to thank someone you should upvote their post is simply not correct.  Whether you're thankful for a post doesn't have bearing on its usefulness.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker You can't think of any ill effects of rewarding people for providing low quality content that isn't actually helpful, or for having an incorrect/unhelpful answer having a positive score when future readers look at the question later?  If that's the case then why do we have voting in the first place?

Comment: see also: [What's so wrong with thanking people?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255390/whats-so-wrong-with-thanking-people)

Answer (score 35):

Because it's noise.

In a perfect world, we wouldn't need comments at all. Ideally, this site (and the other Stack Exchange sites) is simply a question followed by one or more answers that solve the problem. But occasionally we need to get clarification because there's something ambiguous about a post or there's an error.

To "thank" people for helping, vote up their useful answer (or question). If the gave you the solution you needed to your question, then *accept* it.

Or, if you prefer, here's a relevant quote from the Help Center:

> ***What should I do when someone answers my question?***
>   **Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".** Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question.

Comment: Thank you for writing this answer, It is very clear and useful.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I see what you did there

Comment: Upvotes are there to indicate the quality of a post, not to thank someone for spending time on your question.  As is even mentioned right in this question, he may want to thank someone for providing an answer even if that answer *wasn't* helpful to him.

Comment: @Servy quality and correctness and that was helpful to the voter. Caveat: you can select any of the three.

Comment: @Braiam And notice that *none* of those metrics is "to thank the person for posting the question".  It doesn't necessarily need to coincide with *any* of them.

Comment: `inb4 self fulfilling deletion prophecy` Thanks!

Comment: I personally don't like the concept here (not the answer which is verbatim from site). Another description is "you ask a question, a person you have never met reads your question and tries to answer it to the best of his / her abilities". I don't think I have ever just thanked someone in a comment but I think it's appropriate especially if you are writing another comment (even if only to confirm that the answer worked).

Answer (score 13):

Answers should be upvoted if they are *useful*, not necessarily because they contain the right answer.

In fact, this is what the text of the upvote arrow (for an answer) says:

[image]

That means that even if an answer isn't *the* right answer, it should be upvoted if if was useful to you (and you want to upvote it).  We provide very few limitations on what can be upvoted and why: The only thing we really require is that a vote be *for a post* and not *for a person*.

Votes and answering other people's questions are our form of "thanks".  Telling someone "thanks" is too easy, it doesn't require any actual work on your part. *Showing* your thanks by upvoting good answers or by contributing your own answers is what makes the system work.

Comment: I think that if you vote an answer up because it was helpful, even though it was incorrect, a comment should be left to inform others that the answer is incorrect. I've seen too many times on Meta SE about "upvotes for incorrect answers" and the problems they cause.

Comment: @krillgar Comments explaining issues with a post are welcome -- they'll probably be removed at some indeterminate point in the future; but not only that, you can always post an answer explaining two things: 1) the actual answer to the question and 2) why the other answers are incorrect (although helpful).

Comment: I agree. I was suggesting that should be clarified (though those who are on here reading answers usually know that already).

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever use a "clean up folder" feature in Outlook? Do you find yourself having to remove "thank you" or "me too" or "agreed" replies to an otherwise useful thread, possibly with attachments, *before* you push that button?

I think it's for the same reason. In large part providing "thank you" comments in place of other suggested ways is more promoting one's own "I am here and I am polite" attitude. Upvoting, accepting, a comment that adds something on top of what you found useful there -- these are much more appropriate because they actually benefit the community.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: we're all here to learn, so **be friendly and helpful!** (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

*How can you be friendly without saying thanks?*

also mentioned on "how to ask a perfect question" (http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) you can read

- There’s no need to include greetings and sign-offs such as “Hi everyone!” and “Thanks – hope to get an answer soon” in the question.[...]

but also says:

- **Above all, be polite.** Remember that no-one is getting paid to answer your question. [...]

for me it's hard to be polite without some kind of chitchat (?noise?) so i feel free to add a *thanks*-comment whenever an answer was more than helpful namely when **it was friendly and polite!**

> SideNote
>
> don't get fooled by https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/886/posts-with-many-thank-you-answers