# Should answers greet?

Tags: discussion, answers

When we answer a question, should we "greet" the OP?

E.G:

> Cullub,
>   Your question's answer is very simple....

Compared with:

> To fix this simple problem, you....

<sub>See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26234878/3437608

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26234955/3437608</sub>

Comment: No, salutations, greetings, valedictions, etc. are considered noise. Write to *all future visitors* instead.

Comment: Of course not. Greeting == noise, and we expect questions (and thus answers) to be useful to multiple people and not just OP; thus they should address _all_ people who potentially have the issue.

Comment: see also: [Are we supposed to speak like robots when asking questions or are we allowed to be human?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255157/are-we-supposed-to-speak-like-robots-when-asking-questions-or-are-we-allowed-to) and [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Louis that definition is what I was thinking.  Also, "Thanks", "Hi", etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, answers shouldn't greet.

Greetings, like signatures and "thanks" are noise.