# Is there a place on Stack Exchange for programming discussions?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation, forums

It says on Stack Overflow that

> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.

Well, is there a place on the Stack Exchange network where questions can be discussed that don't have a clear answer?  Such as discussing which framework(s) to choose from?

Comment: I'll take that as a "no".

Comment: No, I'm being serious. Chat is the place to go to ask these things. Depending on the room, you might get flamed, but it's still *the* place for discussion.

Comment: that's disappointing.  Seems like a stupid thing to do.  These questions get asked all the time, and putting the discussions in a place where they can't be archived and searched just seems dumb.  Plus, the odds of someone seeing and responding to the question are much lower.  I'm just gonna ask my question on SO anyways.

Comment: @matthew_360 [Hans will disagree with you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254973/456814) (see first section, describing the "bad old days" before [so]).

Comment: @matthew_360 "*I'm just gonna ask my question on SO anyways.*" That is most definitely ***a Bad Idea***.

Comment: @matthew_360 FYI, chat *is* archived and [indexed by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Achat.meta.stackexchange.com+cupcakes+disappear+all+the+time).

Comment: These questions might be asked all the time; the reasons they're not acceptable here have been discussed many, many times as well, and the questions are not welcome because they're noise and clutter. There's no point in rehashing those several discussions over and over again, because the reasons stay the same. Opinions are meaningless, links to resources change/disappear, software recommended disappears/morphs/new software appears, etc., and all of that becomes worthless clutter and noise. This is a knowledge site, not a link or opinion collection. There are sites for that out there already.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a place on the Stack Exchange network where questions can be discussed that don't have a clear answer?

No.

The point of Stack Exchange is about having question and answers.
Discussions don't fit in the question format, and that's done *by very design of this site* (how do you continue discussion? in the comment thread?).

If you want traditional discussion forums, go to the traditional discussion forums.

> Such as discussing which framework(s) to choose from?

[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can reformulate your question to fit requirements of Stack Exchange. To do this, **specify your requirements**, and don't say "I need a framework. Discuss."

Meet [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). [Here's an example question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6/cross-platform-js-php-editor-software-with-ftp-support-and-code-hinting) - notice the questions that can be answered, not discussed. Also, [this place has it's own rules, so be sure to read them](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: ok.. but meta.stackexchange is for discussions about the website... so why can't there be a meta.stackoverflow for programming discussions?

Comment: @matthew_360 see [Should Stack Overflow have a forum where users can talk about anything they want?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254466/456814).

Comment: @matthew_360 They're not "discussions about the site". You asked a specific question about the site, and I'm answering you. (btw. the site you're posting on right now is named "Meta Stack Overflow")

Answer (score -4):

#### tl;dr

The tools listed below not only provide a solution for the use case mentioned above, but also make a great companion to, and expand the benefits of, SO.

If you are familiar with Reddit user interface, save yourself some time and skip to the dashed line below. (9th paragraph)

‐---------------------------

While it isn't in the stack exchange Network, Reddit has an excellent community for this type of discussion. To join, follow the steps I've listed below:

First, you'll need to create a Reddit account, if you don't have one already. Next, search *software engineering* in the search bar provided via the Reddit interface. The community, which is called **r/softwareengineering**, should be listed among the results. This is an excellent resource, imo, not to mention and unlimited source of entertainment. I also believe that it is *exactly* what you are referring to in your question.

The user interface (experience?) is a lot like that of a stack exchange site. Members are able to create posts containing  content on any topic related to software engineering.

Posts can be opinion-based, fact-based, or question based. Some toasts are nothing more than a picture with a caption spanning two or three sentences. The rules on posting are a lot less strict than they are on SE. However, if your post is offensive, spam, or just inherently bad somehow, the community will come together to let you know.

Once you have submitted your post, the entire Community will be able to see it on the main page for the community. For many, it will also appear in their Reddit feed. Additionally, everyone has notifications turned on by default. Anyone who hasn't disabled them will get a (title/summary) notification of your post.

All other members are able to upvote, downvote, or reply to your post. In my opinion, this is where the enjoyment lies.

Users are able to reply to replies. This type of reply is nested beneath the comment to which it is replying. The result ends up looking a bit like XML or HTML nesting.

It is not uncommon for a single post to generate thousands of comments.

----------‐-------------------------------
While there is a lot more to be said about Reddit in general, I am not trying to write a book, so I'll get back to the development subcommunity.

The thing that I admire most about it is that I can ask any questions I have and my peers will be there to give feedback. It is a lot less structured than SE. It feels let's like documentation and more like conversation.

I am not saying that  this is any kind of replacement for SO. It is definitely not. IMO neither platform is better or worse; they are just different. For me, they each have their own use cases, and they both get a lot of use.

The community is actually split across (at least) two subreddits. In addition to **r/softwareengineering**, there is **r/softwaredevelopment** . While these are technically two separate communities, they function as one for the most part, due to the membership crossover between them. **r/softwarearchitecture** and **r/softwaretesting** are also great resources if those areas interest you.

In summary, I recommend these tools to anyone who spends time on stack overflow. As you will see they perfectly compliment SSO, and together, they can easily serve as an all encompassing reference tool for software engineers.