# Is this question suitable for Stack Overflow? Or maybe another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and its features because in a few job interviews I've been to they've said the key factor in choosing somebody else over me was my somewhat minimal understanding of MySQL.

I want to see what MySQL features people would suggest me to look into to help me get that edge (and also generally improve my knowledge), however, I feel this would/could be rather subjective and not on topic.

Am I right in thinking that?

Comment: As the help states, Stack Overflow is a place for *specific answerable* questions. The best advice I can give for learning any relatively mature technology is to use an authoritative, didactic, proof-read source such as a book, and *actually* implement things using that technology.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you are right - this is highly subjective and therefore not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model.

You could try asking in one of chat rooms that discuss SQL or another forum altogether.

I also think that unless you had the actual hands-on experience that the interviewer is looking for, just having the "book knowledge" of a topic won't necessarily get you far in an interview.

Answer (score 8):

It would indeed be off topic. Who can authoritatively answer that? For some people, master-slave data replication may be *the* thing to look into. For others, some optimisation in `JOIN` queries. There's no objective answer to this question. The best you could end up with is a list of basically all non-trivial features MySQL offers, which doesn't help one bit. Might as well just read the manual from front to back.

Comment: But what if you are forced to use MySQL? Sometimes you can't make that choice yourself; so knowing what the pitfalls are is vital. And not just for job interviews!