# Where's the best place to ask questions about BPMN?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have the book-learnin' end of BPMN, and am in my first real world scenario where nothing follows the textbook examples perfectly.

While I can see BPMN tagged questions on Stack, they seem more related to specific BPMN software and process simulations rather than "should situation X be a data association or a message flow" or "is this an exclusive or non-exclusive gateway" newbie-type questions.

In a perfect world, it'd be a community of BA's sharing their knowledge of how to apply BPMN to situations that are too specific for any textbook to cover. However, from the comments, it appears that such a site doesn't exist.

So of the existing Stack sites, is SO the most appropriate place to post such a question? Or is there a better place?

Comment: [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Comment: @gnat  the answer I feared.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @gnat the OTHER answer I feared. :)

Comment: Depends on the exact question, you might get some results on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ if it's more of a software architecture type question.  Otherwise there are several results for 'BPMN Forum' on google.  As BPMN /can/ be used to directly generate computer programs you could argue it is technically a high-level programming language... but I don't think many would agree

Answer (score -1):

I would say Stack Overflow is probably the *best-suited* site for BPMN-related questions but only because programming is de facto often somehow related to business analysis (i.e., many developers work with business analysts and vice versa). But I don't think that Stack Overflow is the *right* place for these kinds of discussions. [As the first sentence of the people who run Stack Overflow says](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) it

> "is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers"

I am not a programmer but a business analyst myself so this site is, by definition, not intended for me. That is not to say that programmers are not able or should not model business processes. "Programmer" and "Business analyst" are just roles. Sometimes, the same person fills both roles, sometimes you have separate people filling them. But I would put the claim to the community's vote that business analysis and modeling is not a subset of programming and hence deserves a separate site (which would go beyond BPMN and include all types of notations).

I have therefore [created a proposal for a new Stack Exchange community that focuses on business process modeling](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121238/business-process-modeling?referrer=IU7kc0WmXuuHw8-vDBM9aw2). **Please feel free to have a look and provide your inputs if you think there is merit in such a community !**