# Add recommendation engine features to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Over the years I've seen many questions asking for recommendations and while virtually all of them ended up being closed as off-topic/Stack Overflow not being a recommendation engine - I also benefited from many of the answers and saw many of the questions and answers get pretty high scores despite being closed (e.g. [What is the best way to learn jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836725/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-jquery?s=1|0.7524)).

Why not allow asking for recommendations? Yes, the answers might be highly opinionated, but that's what voting is for. If some answer gets outdated - it can be edited out. I know that there might be some other sites that are open to recommendations, but I don't really want to go elsewhere - Stack Overflow is the place where I can find many experts willing to provide some really good recommendations. From best API for the job to best learning resources to learn a language/API/technique - these are some of the things that are often more valuable than most of the questions and answers I see.

If there are some inherent problems with recommendations maybe we could - require moderation for answers from low reputation users, provide easier way to give multiple answers, report answers as outdated, score them differently, since they would likely bring a lot of heated up and down-voting, tag recommendation requests specially so they can be filtered in/out, allow to merge duplicate recommendation requests into one wiki etc...

I strongly believe that Stack Overflow would benefit from a few features that would make it great for not only searching for debugging help, but also help them learn how to do it themselves.

Sort of like - "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: This was [tried before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144), it failed miserably as topics degenerated to watercooler-style humor rather than actual discussions.

Comment: _"..but that's what voting is for."_ The problem with voting for opinions is that you don't get the _best answers_ floating to the top. You instead get the _most popular opinions_ floating to the top. Voting is to help highlight the best answers, not the most popular opinions. On top of that, Stack Overflow is here to be a _knowledge base_, not an opinion base, which is pretty much why it wouldn't work well.

Comment: @Kendra: That also happens on other types of answers, but at least there we mostly have a weaker effect and (most of the time) an acceptable correlation with quality.

Comment: "This was tried before ... failed" - perhaps because some new features would be necessary to facilitate the surfacing of good links and cleanup  of the topics.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, I had a brief connection issue and couldn't edit my comment to say that- Then got called off for a bit. Thanks. Filip Skakun- "new features" would mean extra work for the developers, probably plenty of extra resources, and moderating it all will take _a lot_ of time from the _volunteers that already clean up the site._ As it currently stands, I doubt the SE Team will find this worth their time, or worth ours.

Comment: So how else can I find well reviewed, rated and researched recommendations for learning resources or tools? I do agree that this might involve some effort to get it going, but it is something that people need exactly because they ask these questions daily, so I believe it is worth the effort to explore. Closing them is also an effort and may also seem unhelpful and rude and deter developers from using SO even if this is the rule du jour.

Comment: @FilipSkakun _"So how else can I find well reviewed, rated and researched recommendations for learning resources or tools?"_ Ask your friends and coworkers what worked for them. Ask a forum. Check the chats- It depends on the chat, of course, but I'm sure at least some of them can point you in the right direction. Google it. But do not ask on SO and expect your question to stay open. The effort that would be involved in moderating them would greatly outweigh the effort needed to simply close and delete them.

Comment: But it might be worth the effort! There might not be a chat on the topic. Your friends/colleagues might not have the answer either and it would be strongly opinionated if it came from just one source. Having a place with many good developers to vet the answer is what's missing. You can think of many simple mechanisms to make it work. Allow to "strongly protect" questions so only high reputation users could answer it without approvals, make it harder in general to comment and more tools to keep answers up to date are some quick ideas. I don't think SO is about being low effort but about helping

Comment: @Martijn Re: "This was tried before" - were there any special mechanisms enabled to make it work or was it simply a policy change that allowed for recommendations? A policy change is the simplest answer to fight a problem, but not necessarily the best one. If something doesn't work - you can simply forbid it or you can do something to make it work.

Comment: @FilipSkakun How would it be worth the effort? It would still be strongly opinionated coming from SO, so that isn't the best argument. Even if you limit the answers, as Bradley mentions below, they will mostly be link-only OR the high-rep users would flat out refuse to answer and add _noise_ to the site. SO gets 7k-8k new questions per day. That already takes a lot of time to moderate, which means to keep the site clean moderation can't be too hard. Having to go back and verify recommendation answers will take more time out of that and (cont.)

Comment: @FilipSkakun what users are going to want to do that when there's already more crap to take care of coming in from new users that don't care to read and understand the SO guidelines? It would be adding to the workload of the already busy mods and high-rep users that would care to moderate such questions. On top of that, if only high-rep users can answer, what if I, a newer programmer with low rep, have an amazing answer? I can't post it, if it's harder to comment, I doubt I'll be able to, and then my knowledge goes to waste.

Comment: @Kendra It would be worth the effort because it would allow people to find good resources to learn or solve their problems which is what Stack Overflow already is about in many ways. There are already plenty of good recommendation-type questions and answers, but they are all closed and so keeping them up to date is broken. For many questions - a link only answers is perfectly fine. If there is a best site to start learning XAML - answering with a link to the site might be the answer. There are also answers that would be too long to copy and so a link is the only viable answer. (cont.)

Comment: @Kendra It can't be too hard to moderate a question with a list of link answers or is it? It might be one thing actually worth moderating most too since having a good start in learning is better than fixing problems caused by someone not having a good start in the first place. I didn't suggest only high-rep users could answer, but that only high-rep can do it without a review so anyone could post an answer, but it would only be visible after moderation. I also think that having 20 answers with 1-3 being great (and so upvoted) and 10 of them being total crap is better than googling randomly.

Comment: I'm not asking about why opinion-based questions can't be answered or implemented. I don't think recommendations are fully opinion-based. [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe) would be closer, but it doesn't address recommendations at all. Having a list of recommendations that you could upvote or downvote is not something I have seen work anywhere else.

Comment: I can see that there is a possibility this would fail and a similarity between recommendations and opinion-based questions, but there are many questions that require expert opinion to answer. I'm wondering if maybe have a way for moderators to automatically move a question like that to another SE site like [Software Recommendations.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if most people don't want it on SO?

Comment: Also I feel discouraged from using SO when I get 14 downvotes for a suggestion aimed at helping people solve problems. Or meta.SO at least. Makes me feel like meta.SO is a cesspool of SO.

Comment: Not a dupe, recommendation problems are a different beast.

Comment: I feel that you're just sort of handwaving away issues with recommendation questions.  Thing is, *there is no right answer*.  None.  Votes aren't going to be on answer correctness, but that specific recommendation's popularity.  You also get link-only answers, which are almost *always* utter crap, and often spam from others promoting their own tools.  And those answers quite often don't withstand the test of time.  Keeping them constantly up to date would require an army of people continually vetting the links.  It would burn out those you need the most: the experts.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this depends on how you define a "Recommendation" question.

*Library* recommendations are off-topic here; but on-topic at [Software Recommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). They even have a [library] tag!

*Tutorial* recommendations (or "Where to Learn X?") are off-topic.

*How do I* or *What is the best way to* questions are **just fine** provided they meet the rest of the quality standards.

Thus, the only case you are asking for would be to allow tutorial recommendations, which has the (obvious) major flaw: **The answers are invariably link only**. A full tutorial on a technology is way too long for a Stack Overflow answer, and while a set of links can be useful, the links can go dead, and we haven't really put information on the site; see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Granted, many people have the question "How do I learn C#?" (and it shows up at least once a day!), but its just not a good fit for a Q&A site. Other than a bunch of links, that question is *impossible* to answer.

Comment: I don't think Software Recommendations.SE is what I need since that one is too general while SO is about programming. Tutorial recommendations being off-topic is exactly what I want to change since tutorial/book/training recommendations is exactly what helps developers learn before they ask stupid questions that could be answered after spending half an hour going through a good tutorial. Perhaps the way to handle link only answers to recommendations is actually an answer in itself. Let's ONLY allow short link + title answers to recommendation requests to avoid long and subjective discussions.

Comment: @FilipSkakun By the same token, we are not google. Put "C# Tutorial" into a search engine, and you will have plenty of places to start. Granted, it doesn't come with the "expert recommended" tag, but when you are just starting; does it really matter?

Comment: There are good ways to start learning things. There are good books that you can recommend depending on whether someone wants to learn in depth or get quick into action. Similar for tutorials, training videos etc. If a link goes dead - we should allow to fix or remove it. There wouldn't be one good answer, but we could help surface the interesting ones through voting.

Comment: It does matter because there are plenty of bad tutorials and finding the right keywords might be hard if you're just starting. Sometimes there are just too many things to choose from. Sometimes it seems like it's impossible to find a good place to start. I'm for example having problems finding a good PowerShell tutorial for programmers. There is a good 1000 page book that goes in depth too much. There are things for IT people, but I couldn't find anything that would help me automate my workstation, automate VS etc. There's no better place for me to find an answer to such question than SO.

Comment: @FilipSkakun Honestly, I can see your point, and I would never reccommend *starting* programming from the web for that reason. At the same time, its not that difficult to take a little knowledge and turn it into a good search or question. In your example, googling "Powershell tutorial" turned up this on the second result: http://powershelltutorial.net/ After scanning it, I would imagine it could get you far enough that you could either make a better search, or have enough information to ask a specific (answerable) question here.

Comment: @FilipSkakun Granted, thats a very difficult thing for a new programmer to do. It is *vital* however, that they learn to do it! Btw, some tags do have a few tutorial links in their wiki, or even tutorial canonical questions. More could be added in theory, but in all reality you can get started without "expert" help (and then we will tell you all the bad practices you learned :) ).

Comment: Well then, perhaps the way to address it might be to have an official place to link to learning resources in the tag wikis. Having these be links to recommendation request questions might still be beneficial. One thing SO might be better at than bingoogle is more curated answers or more specific recommendations. Powershell for developers is one thing. "Learning JavaScript if you are a C# developer" might be another. These might have ready googlable answers, but there might be newer/niche topics where the answer wasn't written yet and SO could provide maintained curation to keep it up to date.