# What should be the exact purpose of a question?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have had a few instances where I have had very specific issues that I simply couldn't find answers to on the internet. There have been other issues where I simply needed general knowledge about a topic, but still could not find an answer. Is there a particular type of question which Stack Overflow is geared towards, or is it simply contingent on you having put in enough effort prior to turning to Stack Overflow and formulating a clear and concise question?

By the way, I do appreciate the irony of this post, and I'm sorry in advance if the answer to my question is, "Not for this."

Comment: Could you clarify what you feel is missing from the [guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help center?

Comment: I had searched for something like this and failed, which perhaps could be my answer. That link perfectly answers my question, however I had imagined the "help" tab to be reserved more for technical help rather than general help, which I realize now was a bad assumption. Thanks for pointing me here, I don't know that I would have found it otherwise and this whole help center is exactly the type of info I was after.

Comment: @LordFarquaad You might need to notice, these help pages are slightly different throughout other [SE Sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites), but most of the policies are just shared.

Comment: related: [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The words *general knowledge* already indicate that the question is very likely to be too broad for Stack Overflow. Such questions could be closed with the following reason:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Note that the goal of Stack Overflow, as mentioned on the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), is (emphasis mine):

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of *detailed* answers to every question about programming.

You can't expect a *detailed* answer to a question about *general* knowledge. At least not one that would fit into the Q&A format we have here.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks. However, a while ago I had a question titled "What permissions does a client/server application have?", which explained a little bit of my situation, then asked, "what permissions are granted to the server end of the application?" I understand that question in particular was poorly crafted, but is this type of question also deemed too broad?  Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358054/what-permissions-does-a-client-server-application-have

Comment: @LordFarquaad I've added comment to your question... There is really no way to answer it in current state without exact knowledge of your setup (which makes question into that funny group existed on SO for some time when question is "too localized" and "too broad" at the same time).

Answer (score 4):

There are a large number of questions where the most useful answer or comment tends to be "the magic word for your concept is...".  For example, "that panoramic thing you do is called image stitching" or "this is handled in the transcribe package" or "you are trying to generate a nonce."

These questions usually have some common traits:

- They are easy to research details for once the key term has been identified.  Once the key term is found,
- The question is usually down voted into oblivion or outright deleted by active community members who take affront of the vagueness of the question.
- Answers to the question are also usually down voted.
- A fair number of these questions have bounties.  Not because they are hard, but because it keeps the questions from being deleted and may have a drive by answer.

It is a human trait that some who question are deemed to be unprepared to ask.  Perhaps this is an area where a template for phrasing the question would be useful. As it stands, these are questions useful for solving problems but not for building a database of useful knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this page in the Help Center doesn't get enough visibility, so here is a straight verbatim reproduction of it as a wiki entry.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ->

[Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) > [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

### What topics can I ask about here?

Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel [the best Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have a bit of **source code** in them, but if your question generally covers…

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Please [look around](/search) to see if your question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer). Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be [put on hold by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) until they are improved.

[Click here for tips on how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that are likely to be well-received by the community and attract good answers.

**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**

1. Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
2. Questions about *a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error*. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.
3. Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.
4. Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.
5. Questions about *general computing hardware and software* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.
6. Questions on *professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

**If your question is not specifically on-topic for Stack Overflow**, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites). If your question would be of interest to …

- Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com).
- Professional system and network administrators, ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).
- Users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems, ask on [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com).
- Database administrators and professionals, ask on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com).
- SharePoint enthusiasts, ask on [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).

If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Comment: @Peter Note that you *corrected* a quoted text. It seems like the mistake is present across the whole Stack Exchange Network. I created a post on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281353/area-51-in-help-center-is-not-written-according-to-trademark-guidance

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes, the purpose of a question is to ask something that will reduce the need for people who come up with the same question to post that question, since it would have already been sufficiently answered if the question was specific enough to cover the question space. If I am curious whether I should use int or int32_t in my programs, I can look up [Difference between int32, int, int32_t, int8 and int8_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515874/difference-between-int32-int-int32-t-int8-and-int8-t) and likely won't ask it since so many questions of this sort have been asked already that people will look at me funny if I even try, so each well formed question of this sort prevents countless more from being asked.

There is also another purpose, which is to bring up an interesting discussion to reconsider questions to whose answers are no longer sufficient due to changes in technology/increase/decrease of question space, where one question could have been specific at one time, but now too broad to answer and requires being split up into new questions and discussed once again. This also includes situations where answers to questions are no longer true due to changes in technology, e.g. answers that JavaScript can only be used in browser were very popular very little time ago, and are now downright lies. Here is an excellent example of a question that changed context quite a few times in recent history: [Why use XML(SOAP) when JSON so simple and easy to handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323950/why-use-xmlsoap-when-json-so-simple-and-easy-to-handle).

Another reason is to bring up something an existing answer to a question has overlooked, or not made clear enough. Thus there may be answers to the question, but they still cause confusion since they leave out important things or don't emphasize them well enough, so it is fair to ask whether a solution to an existing question has left something out since you are not convinced that their answer answers your question. An example of this is that if I am trying to understand hash tables but have no idea how buckets or probe sequences get resolved. In this case, I try finding answers but struggle, so I ask a naive question like the one I posted earlier ([How do hash tables resolve bucket ambiguity and probes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406418/how-do-hash-tables-resolve-bucket-ambiguity-and-probes)) granted I should have formed it better as it is a disgrace of a question but it was bothering me at the time, and now google searching "hash table probe ambiguity" brings up one StackOverflow result on the first page up from none) in turn benefitting both the person searching and StackOverflow, and I am sure somebody someday will relate to my confusion and appreciate the existence of the question and its' answers. And even though the question is pretty bad, it gives a new space for people to improve upon if they end up having new question, rather than if the question has never been asked before where in some cases, new interesting questions won't appear until less interesting holes in existing questions have been answered for those that are struggling.