# Could I ask about possible causes for an issue?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

Such as, if there are some common reasons for causing an issue, could I ask for them? E.g.

> What are the possible reasons for memory leaks?

I know *strong delegate*, *strong self for block usage*; is there other reason that causes this issue?

Comment: Such question may come out _too-broad_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but how can i ask this qeastion? or other way?

Comment: It's not like _every_ question can be asked at stack overflow.

Comment: see also [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Comment: "list questions" with an endless list of possible answers don't work on Stack Overflow: Questions that are related to a real-world problem tend to do best. Can you specify what exactly it is that you want to know/learn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible. You can't just ask "Why does my application crash" either – in that case, we can only help if you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and/or show the part of the code causing the crash together with the full error message. What you need to do is use a tool called a 'profiler' and examine your application with it. If you have a *specific* question (e.g. "Why does this way of declaring variables cause a memory leak?"), that's usually fine (though probably duplicate).

As πάντα ῥεῖ mentions, questions like yours are usually closed as too broad. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.