# Could I ask about information I do not understand in Instruments?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

I do not understand the information shown in my Instruments - what is the yellow background information?

Could I ask this question on Stack Overflow?

[image: I]

Comment: This is definitely better than the question [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338712/could-i-ask-a-issues-reason-in-stackoverflow). But you could at least tell us *why* you think this is a memory leak. Because it has no yellow line?

Comment: Ah, I see you put that in the image link. No, you still can't ask that, you should read a tutorial about Instruments first.

Comment: @Glorfindel Got it, thanks, I will read the tutorial first, if tutorial has no introduce to it, could I ask this question on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is at least reasonably scoped, unlike the one you proposed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338712/could-i-ask-a-issues-reason-in-stackoverflow). It's on-topic, but it might be downvoted because of the lack of research. You can find the answer to this question by Googling the right terms, or by following a tutorial on Instruments. There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335057/how-to-check-heap-memory-using-instruments-in-xcode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685139/what-is-color-block-of-instruments-mean/22722424#22722424).

Comment: good answer, should search!