# Can I ask this type of question I don't know how to realize on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

Our product have an function, and I don't know how to realize it:

[image]

This is the function, live chat with service. I just don't know the service side's interface is how realize, and the app can chat with the service.

How to fast integration and implements it?

Can I ask this type question I don't know how to realize on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Hmmm no. That is way too broad for Stack. We tend to lile questions where you have something done and can't figure out THAT part. We don't do well on "I dunno how to start this"

Comment: @Patrice if not, where can I ask this type question on stackexchange?

Comment: not a great answer.... But.... Not on the network wpuld probably yield better results:/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wouldn't be well received here, or on any other SE site that I know of. You'd probably be better off Googling [something like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile%20app%20chat%20service%20tutorial).