# Why is my question getting flagged as too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, close-reasons

I've been asking the following question for some niche tags:

> [Was any esoteric programming language ever used for other than “educational” purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043229/was-any-esoteric-programming-language-ever-used-for-other-than-educational-pur)

**Edit:**

Keeping a screenshot of the question, (for users with less 10k rep), since the question in question is deleted ATM:

[image]

The question received 2 downvotes and 2 close votes at time of writing here.

I don't get what's actually wrong with it.

- *"Not programming related"* Eso languages are programming related
- *"Too broad"* Doesn't seem to be applicable as close reason, since I'm clearly asking for evidence (and I'm pretty sure there won't be much results)
- *"Not useful for future research"* Well, I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one wondering. I didn't find an appropriate duplicate also.

Comment: because... apparently at least 2 people have decided they think it's too broad.

Comment: @KevinB How's that _too broad_? I provided tags to narrow it down to a very specific field of programming languages, and stated so in my question body as well.

Comment: votes are of course subjective. part of why it requires 5.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, that seems to be a key point. Not to mention _flock of sheeps_.

Comment: hmmmm... This isn't on topic for Stack anyway, broad or not.

Comment: You ask three questions in your question. The close reason states: *Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.** See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.* [emphasis mine].

Comment: @Patrice How so? Regarding the _practical_ part?

Comment: Even your first question delves into the realm of asking for opinions.

Comment: @user0042 pretty much, yes. I fail to see ANY value to a practical programming Q&A site to have such a question. While interesting (I am genuinely curious to its answer now), I can't see why this would be helpful to add to Stack. Our help center is clear. Is your question about a "specific programming problem", a "software algorithm" or "software tools commonly used by programmers"? Not really, no.

Comment: @Patrice That should be a sign that we burninate those kind of tags alltogether, no? TBH that's just a little experiment of mine.

Comment: It seems like it would be impossible to prove an answer of 'No', especially for multiple languages and even more especially when not every language in the question is actually listed.

Comment: @BSMP Well, I'm asking about a whole category of languages.

Comment: Yes, and I think that has something to do with users seeing it as too broad.

Comment: What if the answer is *yes*? What if 20 answers explain why they choose brainfuck and 10 why they didn't after careful evaluation? It is an interesting question for a blog or a forum. Not for a site that claims to have the best answer to your question. Too broad for me.

Comment: @user0042 why burninate these tags? I can ask a decent "how to do X in brainfuck"

Comment: @Patrice Because I could ever answer _"That wouldn't be practical for production code"_, and it's not asking for a _practical_ use case.

Comment: @user0042 no, it's a practical programming problem. You are splitting hairs here, or being obtuse or something.. I can ask "how do I do X" which is a practical programming problem. Not the same as "has anyone ever done X" which is a..... historical question I guess?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe

Comment: see also: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @gnat You seem to be _the librarian_ of Meta SO. THX a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "Too broad" Doesn't seem to be applicable as close reason, since I'm clearly asking for evidence (and I'm pretty sure there won't be much results)

There are several "too broad" tests. One of them is the number of potential answers being essentially infinite. Another of them is the fact that people can change the answer simply by doing something with the language off-site, then pointing to it and declaring it to not be for "educational purposes".

And then there's the fact that it's ultimately a "yes/no" question. Particularly for a question where even if the answer is no right now, the answer can be changed to "yes" simply by someone doing something with such a language.

Then there's the nature of the question itself. It's asking about a poorly defined concept: "esoteric languages". Well, what constitutes "esoteric"? Also, it's not clear what is a "useful product"? Useful to whom?

Overall, this is clearly a question we don't want on this site.

Comment: There's also the fact that it's asking several distinct questions; that's a much less ambiguous criteria for being Too Broad that is met.