# A [conceptual] burnination request

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I just stumbled upon a [conceptual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conceptual) question that was tagged as such. Wow! The tag description is literally meta:

> *Conceptual questions involve programming problems which are not related to program code itself, but with algorithm logic and program architecture.*

So does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?

**No**.

Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

[**Mostly not**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252777/1048572).

And does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

**Not at all**. I say burn!

(There's also a related [concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concept) tag, which should be cleaned up as well, and then probably be renamed to [concept-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_programming) as per its tag description)

Comment: I agree with this concept.

Comment: Yeah, that's about as blatantly Meta as you get. I say we burn it.

Comment: This is quite the maculate conception. I say we make an unholy ghost out of it.

Comment: This tag sounds like it should have been applied to this old question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280736/programatically-calculate-base-colour-required-to-achieve-a-specific-colour-afte

Comment: conceptual programming... isn't that for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com ? Maybe in the mean time edit the tag to state that if they use this tag their question is most likely more suited for that site.

Comment: Inconception ception?

Comment: cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195868/burninate-conceptual-tag