# May I ask questions concerning cloning websites for practise purposes?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it okay to ask questions about how to clone certain features on a website for practise purposes?

Comment: First rule about SO is: You only talk about SO on [meta]

Comment: SO is not a forum.

Comment: yes and no. If you're asking for help with solving a problem that you are having *while* doing so, sure, as long as that problem isn't "i can't do it, do it for me"

Comment: Such a question would almost certainly be Too Broad, given what you've described so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Comment: @gnat:  In what universe would that be a duplicate of this question?  This is asking a very pointed question about what they can ask here, which does relate to programming.  There's nothing tangiental about this question, and we likely already entertain scores of these here.

Answer (score 8):

Fundamentally, you can ask about anything that you have trouble with.  The premise doesn't *really* matter, but we ask that you make sure your question is on-topic.

That said, here's some guidelines to help with that:

- **Don't ask a question without showing some effort.**  Googling *barely* counts as effort.  Show us what you wrote that demonstrates you're at least making an attempt on your own as well.  Without this, **do not bother asking your question**, as it will be downvoted/closed like all other off-topic questions.
- **Don't use the other site as a spec.**  It's fine to ask about how to replicate features, but saying "it should look like THIS when I'm done" is not that helpful, or really that useful.
- **Be prepared to defend your approach.** Sometimes your approach seems unorthodox given what you're attempting to solve (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).  You should be prepared to receive feedback and answer questions based on that confusion.

Comment: Okay, thanks. My question relates to a certain feature I saw on a site. I literally have no idea what plugin or library I can use to do the same thing. I want to ask if I can share a screenshot of it and ask if anyone knows what i can use to do the same thing

Comment: @amries:  Well, no, that's blatantly off-topic.  We don't really do identification-style questions here.