# How to stop people from closing as off-topic when asking how to do something

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Recently most questions that have been most useful to me (mostly regarding javascript) have been closed as off-topic for "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

What is the best way to scale back the use of "closing" these questions?

Many of these are not questions such as "which is better: mac, windows or linux". They are legitimate questions asking for advice about how to integrate multiple components/libraries to perform a task, and most of the recent ones that I have seen have legitimately helpful answers describing various combinations of libraries, etc. that can be combined to perform a specific function.

A typical example might be "what is the best way to stringify an object in NodeJS and then compress it, and reverse the process in the client side browser after sending it over a websocket?". Obviously, the content of the question should describe that the specific issue is compressing/decompressing the JSON (since compression libraries typically want a stream but JSON.stringify and JSON.parse aren't streaming functions), and the goal is to do it efficiently as a stream.

Because this can involve up to five libraries, there are literally thousands of permutations, and typically, a complete solution comes from partial answers by various people. One person may have a solution to the server stringification/compression (which is complicated by the need to stream the JSON string into a compression function), while another answer may have a different solution for how to do this in the browser. Obviously, some people may reference existing answered questions (ie. about the websocket part). But ultimately, a complete answer can be formed.

In other words, some of the questions most likely to be closed as "off-topic" for this reason are also some of the questions that would benefit the community most from the collaborative stack overflow approach.

Or, putting it another way, the current stack overflow standard seems to be that if there is only one way to do something then it is okay to ask about it, but if there are multiple ways, it will be closed as off-topic because people may provide opinionated answers. But it is when there are lots of multiple ways to do something that I want people's actual experience most of all to quickly get to the most tried and true approach.

To summarize; how to get people to be more judicious and scale back the annoying practice of closing legitimate questions as off-topic for "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."?

This is not about asking generic questions. My contrived example specifically asks how to pipeline, on a server, stringifying an object, then compressing it, then sending it over a websocket, and then doing the reverse on the client side. The key issues are how to do this in a streaming pipeline and ensure that the server compression is compatible with the client decompression (since not all tools are available for both the server and client different libraries may be required, but they must be compatible). Had this been a real question instead of an example, the body of the question would have specifically noted that the object may be very large so it would be preferable to not have to use two full size buffers for the uncompressed and compressed data (ie. use streams).

Note that this question is not about actually answering the technical question. It is about not getting questions "closed out" when other people are actually commenting and responding to them (ie. at least some people are finding them useful and valid).

Comment: For these kinds of question to be meaningful you would need to closely define terms like "best" and "efficient", which these kinds of question almost never do.

Comment: @NeilButterworth a very valid point, but these are the types of issues that are raised in the answers. So for my contrived example, somebody may propose a solution that is memory intensive, but fast, while somebody else may propose a solution that has low memory requirements but is slower. Since my contrived example involves both a server and client, there are now four permutations of possible solutions. This is why the discussion is needed.

Comment: We aren't a discussion site or a forum though, we do questions and their answers and that's all. Meta is the nearest we get to discussions.

Comment: Adding one point here: the close-reason *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam* did not originally exist. It was not handed down on a stone tablet from the mountain. It was implemented and enforced *after observing such questions, their responses, and the effects on the site*, and observing the overall effect was *detrimental*. They *don't work* on SE. That's not to say they're bad questions, it is to say th intersection w SE is unworkable

Comment: One might argue that there are indeed many legitimate questions related to programming. That alone does not make them suitable for this site.

Comment: `"What is the best way to scale back the use of "closing" these questions?"` --  your question is being asked backwards. The closings look to be appropriate, and your question should in fact be, "how can I learn to best use this site so that my questions are considered on-topic". The site will not change its rules just for you (or me), and so you (and I) need to learn to adapt our expectations and our site usage to match the site requirements.

Comment: Arguing about question legitimacy is orthogonal to the issue; we don't care how legitimate the question is.  All we care about is how useful it will be to someone in the future.  Recommendation questions *can* be useful, but they are generally more trouble than they're worth.  All you see are the ones that are *left*, which are the ones worth keeping.  What you don't see is all the others that are deleted.

Comment: SO cannot do system design.   If an OP's requirments are posted, they are nearly always unclear.    If they were well-defined, they would be a requirement spec that is too broad.  No thanks.  If an OP wants a system design, I am happy to met with them and discuss terms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Comment: @gnat I don't think it is a duplicate. So far it seems people have two issues: 1) the phrase "what is the best way to ..." instead of "how can I ...". It seems that it would be more useful for experienced SO users to just suggest rewording the question. 2) My contrived example assumed that each step was interrelated to the others. Robert Longson pointed out that compression is baked in to websockets and referred me to an existing question that had already been answered. So my contrived example was actually more specific than the acceptable question. His answer was more useful than closing-out.

Comment: Please remember that my original purpose in raising this discussion was that I noticed how many questions are being "closed out" which I find useful, and judging by the amount of responses to them other people do also (I am guessing they are not the people monitoring the meta discussions though). It just seems like there could be a better way to get these questions back on track rather than cutting them off cold.

Comment: Again, question legitimacy is irrelevant.  If they want us to recommend some software or a tool, it's off-topic.  There *might* be an XY problem in there, but it's generally going to be on the asker to update their question to fix that aspect, as we probably won't have enough information to do so.  Closure does not prevent commenting, or editing.  All it does is prevent answers, which, for off-topic questions is what we want to happen.

Comment: @fbueckert Yes, I understand that that is the world as it is today; but this is the meta area, where we can talk about the world as it could be :-) What you described means that alot of answers are ending up as comments instead of answers. I am just suggesting to consider if there are alternatives to the quick "close-out" such as proposing to the OP of a question to rephrase "what is the best way to ..." to "how can I ..." instead of closing something out.

Comment: They can make those changes once it's closed.  Their question, in the *current* state, is not one we want answers to.  That's why we close it.  Once it has been fixed, the question can be reopened.  *All* closing does is prevent answers, to questions that are problematic in some form or another.  Solve the problem if you want to be able to get answers for it.

Comment: @Casey if closure was immutable, I would agree with you. Right now closure carries a very useful message explaining what needs to change on the question for it to be in a position to be reopened....

Comment: It seems like the issue isn't that they're being closed but that they're getting closed for the wrong reason. Your example is too broad and primarily opinion based, not a recommendation request.

Answer (score 12):

Your example question would appear to be too broad i.e. It asks multiple distinct questions at once.

1. what is the best way to stringify an object in NodeJS
2. and then compress it,
3. and reverse the process in the client side browser
4. after sending it over a websocket?

Break down the problem into the component parts and explain what your problem is with each part e.g What definition of "best" do you have for part 1? Least execution time, least memory used, something else? Each of these could and probably should be a separate question.

Also what have you done thus far to solve these problems and where have you got stuck, it's much easier to help you if you say here's what I've already written but things go wrong here where I expect this to happen and yet some other thing happens instead.

Comment: The problem with breaking it down is that items 1 and 2 are inter-related, and item 3 has to be compatible with items 1 and 2. Agreed that item 4 is a throwaway, and only included in the question to provide context for the conditions under which 1-3 are being performed.

Comment: So 2 is what compression can I use in Node that is compatible with browsers ability to uncompress? And 1 is How can I stringify something in Node such that it can be consumed in a browser. Compression is orthogonal to the underlying data content.

Comment: No, AFAIK browsers don't decompress websocket data. This requires an external javascript library. Which is why whatever library/format is used on the server has to be compatible with what is used in the browser. But maybe I am wrong and if questions like this weren't closed somebody would be able to provide a concise clarification. Compression is not orthogonal to the question - it is the question (there are hundreds of examples how to do this without compression). And please remember, this is a contrived question to make a point (for this meta question).

Comment: Sure they do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646680/could-websocket-support-gzip-compression#comment15442271_11647130 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792831 which is why if you ask about that specific issue you can get an answer.

Comment: So why isn't your comment above a legitimate answer to a legitimate question? Is it really just the specific use of the word "best"? If so, can we please just incorporate a pipeline into stack overflow to convert the phrase "what is the best way to ..." to "how can I ..."?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646680/could-websocket-support-gzip-compression is a legitimate question with answers, it's not closed as off-topic. It does however only ask one thing and does not try to conflate multiple issues into one question. Your main problem is your example is too broad, if we split it up to fix that we get an issue with one of the parts being unclear because it's ill defined. Note that the individual parts are probably already on the site as existing Q&A as I've just demonstrated.

Comment: I mean that I would have no issues with you answering MY contrived question with a reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646680/could-websocket-support-gzip-compression and a note that it had already been asked and answered. That would be helpful, closing it as off-topic is not.

Comment: @Casey Except your question isn't a good question; you've conflated several different issues into a single one, and assumed the solution has to take all of them into account.  That's usually too broad.  If that's not helpful, the onus is on you to narrow it down so that it can actually *be* answered.  We're not trying to be helpful to just you; but also *everybody else* that comes across this question because they have the same problem.

Comment: @fbueckert no, it is a pipeline. Stringifying an object is a batch operation, compression is a stream operation, sending on a websocket is a batch operation. The question is about whether they can all be integrated into a single streaming pipeline. The sending over a websocket part was just to give context to the other parts. The client/server aspect alluded to the idea that the different sides may have to do it differently, but they both need to be compatible.

Comment: @RobertLongson Note that per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API "Starting in Gecko 8.0 (Firefox 8.0 / Thunderbird 8.0 / SeaMonkey 2.5), the deflate-stream extension to the WebSocket protocol has been disabled, since it's been deprecated from the specification drafts. This resolves incompatibilities with some sites."

Answer (score 10):

You may be looking at the wrong symptom here.

The problem is seldom in the title; it's often to do with what's actually being asked.  Your example of "which is better: mac, windows or linux" has problems in that it's not clear what's being asked; the goal, if any, is ill-defined at best, and thus cannot be objectively answered.

Your counterexample suffers from the same flaw.

> "What is the best way to stringify an object in NodeJS and then compress it, and reverse the process in the client side browser after sending it over a websocket?"

Two immediate questions:

1. Who *cares* what the "best" way is if it works effectively for your use case? (e.g. why are you asking about "best"?)
2. What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

The problem as stated with that question is that it's not really clear what one is trying to accomplish.  If readers see a clear goal in mind, then that *improves* the chances of it being on-topic here.

Comment: let's not get hung-up on the use of the word "best". Bearing in mind that it is a contrived question to use an an example for the meta question (and not a fully formed question in its own right), I am not sure what is the most concise way to say "which method, which is obviously not needlessly wasteful of resources, can be used to ..." (the key word being "needlessly"). But even as a contrived question, I think it is fairly straightforward. JSON objects are just text, with lots of duplication, so there is significant bandwidth savings if they can be compressed before transmission.

Comment: @Casey:  You would be surprised, then, to discover that there are a ***very*** large number of questions which get caught in moderation hell behind the phrase "best".  It's *so* subjective that it's actually a really bad idea to even mention it.  That said, to your main point, this is the kind of information I as a prospective answerer would be interested in knowing - **your intent**.  You wish to reduce bandwidth usage when sending JSON payloads.  Now we're getting somewhere with the question.

Comment: @Casey:  From the above, this begs the question of how *much* data is being transmitted, what your data constraints are, and what your solutions have been up to this point in regards to compression.  It may even be the case that compression is the wrong solution for your use case.  You don't know that immediately since you've defined your solution as your question when you *probably* shouldn't have.

Comment: Ironically, my contrived example really is something I have been looking into, and the reason for my original post is because of the number of questions I saw recently which were "closed out" for the reasons I stated. I have been using SO for about six years now, and never noticed this phenomenon before. But I only recently started using javascript, and it seems this phenomenon may be related to the fast moving pace of web development and people trying to keep up with the changes. Would be nice if SO could adapt and accommodate the concept of "current best practices" (or something).

Comment: Again @Casey, I get the impression that you're trying to blame the system instead of you wanting to actually repair the question you have.  Your question *sounds* legit.  It's just the case that as posed, it's too broad and sounds more like solutionizing as opposed to an actual question.

Comment: It is not about my contrived question. It is about the frequency with which I am seeing so many other questions being cut-off. In order to open the discussion I contrived an example question which (in my opinion) is typical of many questions which add value but are being cut-off relegating lots of useful information to be buried in comments instead of answers.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow anymore @Casey.  Devoid of context or purpose, questions which follow the same pattern as your contrived example are not going to survive for very long here.  I hope that above in comments I at least highlighted what an OP should be prepared to do if confronted with this scenario to make it *less* likely that their question will be closed.

Comment: I should stress this:  **we're not your enemy**.  We're not trying to be jerks here.  What we *are* doing is enforcing a high standard of our questions and content here.  The choice then lies with the OP to either rise to that standard, or post on another part of the Internet.

Answer (score 9):

The ultimate goal of Stack Overflow has always been, at least as far as I can remember, to build a complete collection of questions and answers.

The issue with "best way to do X"-questions lies within "best". What is best? Is it the fastest, the safest? Who defines best? YOU do! The person asking the question.

Consider a question such as "Best way to transfer data from PC1 to PC2". The fastest is to send it directly, without any checks. That's fast, but it sure as hell isn't safe. The safer approach would be to check the data transmitted, which slows down the process. All subjective.

The issue that subjective Q&As introduce is that you can have a million questions asking basically the same, with ever so slight modifications, which imo is better suited for a discussion, i.e. in chat, or using a different platform.

Answer (score 8):

First make sure your question meets the *on-topic* criteria stated here

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Also make sure your question doesn't fall into this category:

- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Last but not least make sure you're asking a good question, more information can be found here:

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

As it sounds the kind of question you're asking about fall into the category *primarily opinion based* which is *off-topic*. As stated in comments you'll need to define *best*, *most efficient* better to make your questions more meaningful.

Comment: I am suggesting that I am getting value out of these questions; and gauging by the responses of other people before the questions are being closed, other people are getting value also. I am suggesting to reconsider the criteria in the links you included above.

Comment: I wanted to upvote this to guard against a post deletion but the advice here is so *blasé* I cannot bring myself to do it.

Comment: @Makoto Did you mean to call me _arrogant_? If so I should probably flag your comment as being _unkind_ ;)

Comment: If you consider yourself to be your advice, you may interpret my comment as you so desire.

Comment: @Casey: We don't close questions based on whether someone can manage to scrape together some kind of value from them. We close questions on the basis of what will generate easily indexable useful information that is generally useful to a range of people.