# Which Stack Exchange site is appropriate for my question about CPUs and operating systems?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

My question is about how an OS kernel reports the CPU load usage using a command such as `top` in Linux/Unix, or using a function such as `os.getloadavg()` in Python. I specifically want to know if the OS reserves CPU processing for the OS (stdout, peripheral listeners, etc.) and whether or not that reserved CPU processing is included in the output of those commands.

I'm not sure which SE branch is appropriate for my question. I suspect that it may either be [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [Linux & Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour), or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: I'd go with Unix & Linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- If you're interested in the mechanism itself, from kernel design perspective, and specifically for Linux (i.e. possibly with kernel source and/or docs references), go to *Unix & Linux*.
- If you rather need the view from a programming language's perspective -- i.e. what an API specification says on this matter, go to *Stack Overflow*.
- If your primary focus is to rather apply the theory to achieve some specific system administration task, go to *Server Fault*.

  - but not if you lack the theoretical background to understand a practical answer and/or didn't look through essential system administration reading -- this is a prerequisite at SF to pass the professionalism test

Comment: What about software engineering Sir? When can this question be eligible to make it there OR what does the forum addresses to? design patterns, methodologies, does and don'ts at the software engineering level?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, if they haven't done the required prerequisites for ServerFault's professionalism test, would it be suitable to ask on Super User, as that site is not targeted at professionals.

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena _Software Engineering_ is about designing your software, not about the current design of some existing software. So off topic for it.

Comment: @DoctorJones The topic is too deep for Super User. The specifics of some kernel mechanism is not something that a user, as opposed to a programmer or a system administrator, directly sees or deals with.