# Is it bad form to post conceptual questions about data structures?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

I'm struggling to understand why this question was heavily downvoted: [What does it mean if a data structure's members are stored by hash value rather than by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799628/what-does-it-mean-if-a-data-structures-members-are-stored-by-hash-value-rather)

Comment: Seems like lack of research. It's a rather basic question of how a set/hash works.

Comment: I thought elementary questions were okay since I regularly come across them with several hundred upvotes when web searches lead me to Stack Overflow.

Comment: They are "OK" in the sense they can be on-topic. But they can still be downvoted if users find them not useful, poorly researched, or not clear.

Comment: All elementary questions have already been asked and answered.  The comment gave you the cue, probably would have led you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692077/difference-between-array-set-and-dictionary-in-swift), as well as lots of other web pages.  Avoiding duplicating this kind of info was a primary reason for founding SO.  Putting a bounty on the question prevented everybody from linking to them, little else they can do but vote.

Comment: Yes, it is bad form to ask basic questions that can be answered by an utter minimum of study/research. Google "hash value" gives this wiki as first hit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function. It should suffice to get a basic understanding of the topic. SO isn't an interactive beginner tutorial, nor is it "how-to-Google" support.

Comment: see also: [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252777/839601)

Comment: Meta friends, no need to pound the linked question with additional votes, IMO. The message is already clear enough. Dupe-close votes might be more useful, maybe?

Comment: @yivi I agree, pounding the linked question with additional votes is not constructive. The comments to this question are however, except for the duplicate suggestion.

Comment: Why do you believe the duplicate suggestion is not constructive? If the question **is** a duplicate, wouldn't it be useful for future visitors to find the related resources? (BTW, haven't voted on your questions in any way myself).

Comment: The particular question that it's a "possible duplicate" of is a feature request masqueraded as a question. I interpreted the suggestion of redirecting the linked question to it as passive-aggressively saying the question is an awful waste of time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant voting to close the **linked** question, not this meta question. If an appropriate dupe target is found, which I guess should be possible give the question, marking that question as a dupe helps everyone, IMO.

Comment: Got to agree that the duplicate closure of this Meta question doesn't make much sense. Whatever the merits of the particular question about hash sets being discussed, I don't see how it's "not too specific" or "open-ended"... and even if it were, that wouldn't make this Meta question (about whether a particular question is okay on Stack Overflow) a duplicate of *that* Meta question (about where to ask questions that aren't okay on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Those early basic questions without research would get downvotes today. They would also get upvotes & answers from people who want to answer anyway, to help and/or for rep and/or etc despite it lacking research effort.