# Help asking a question that may not have a specific answer: I want to see how others would have solved a particular problem

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

Good evening,

I am rather new to this site and also rather new to coding.  I have finished coding a discounted cash flow problem but I am wondering if there are better ways to reach the same solution that I reached.  I want feedback, suggestions for better approaches, and correction.  I am wondering how to appropriately ask this question. If posting the code and asking for correction and feedback is inappropriate for this site, what similar question can I ask to get similar answer?  If such a question is not fitting for stack overflow, do you have any suggestions for sites on which I can elicit feedback?

Comment: Asking for debugging help is okay, provided it comes with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//meta.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and debug/error logs if applicable to help us repro the issue. See the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/584192) before posting your question.

Comment: If you're asking how can your code be improved (but doesn't provide a measurable way of your end goal), that's too broad because it is opinion-based and the correct answer is subjective. You can try Reddit for questions like this.

Comment: @SamuelLiew consider adding to duplicates list this one: [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252777/839601)