# How do I create a glossary on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

Is there a possibility to create a glossary within Stack Overflow for key words / definitions to align people within an organisation? If yes, how can I create one?

Comment: Is this for Teams?

Comment: What do you mean with Teams?

Comment: well, outside of teams, there are no organisations, so if you're not talking about teams... there's no real place to put a glossary for a particular organisation. If it pertains to a specific tag, the tag wiki might suffice.

Comment: Teams is a service for, well... teams. See https://stackoverflow.com/teams but since you're not aware of it I guess it's not a question about teams.

Comment: A glossary [would not seem to be on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on this site. Why do you think it's appropriate to create such a thing here?

Comment: I'm not sure it's entirely what you're after but throwing it out there in case it may be helpful. You might be able to base something on https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site - that was developed mainly for cataloguing/tagging canonical/related Python questions on Stack Overflow... (https://sopython.com/canon/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Comment: *key words* or *[keywords](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keyword#Noun)*?

Comment: There is [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms), which is network-wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that you'd need to do externally, perhaps as a wiki that you maintain within the organization. I've seen companies do this (and make it public) in the past so that their users would understand what tags they monitor, collections of questions linked by topic, etc - this is something you'd maintain on your side.

[Stack Overflow For Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) (which is a paid product) does offer some additional functionality that would be useful for this, but still not an actual *glossary* by definition, so you'd still have to find a way to make it work for you.

You might want to start with just a simple wiki within the organization, and see how that grows if what you're mostly interested in is grouping stuff from public Q&A (if I understand your need correctly).