# Make [glossary] a synonym of [terminology]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Tl;Dr [glossary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary) is being used on questions about terms. We already have [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology) for those questions.

---

### [glossary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary)

Tag excerpt:

> list of terms and definitions used in a larger document

It has 96 questions. The frequent tab for this tag returns 30 questions, none of these questions are about glossaries instead they are about the meaning of certain terms, i.e.,

- [What is a 'Closure'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36636/1595451) (also has [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology))
- [Abstraction VS Information Hiding VS Encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24626/1595451)

Top users

[glossary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary) Top answerers have 1-2 answers.

Last 30 days

In the last 30 days there was 0 anwswers and 0 questions.

### [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

Tag excerpt

> Questions about the meaning or usage of programming terms.

It has 2,189 questions. The frequent tab for this tag returns 388, the top of these questions are about the meaning of certain terms, i.e.,

- [What is JSONP, and why was it created?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067472/1595451)
- [What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130794/1595451)

Top users

Top answerers

- 1 user has 9 answers
- 1 user has 8 answers
- 2 uses have 5 answers

Last 30 days

- 21 posts were create since 2020-08-01

---

A note about [glossaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossaries)

### [glossaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossaries)

Tag excerpt. This tag hasn't a tag excerpt.

It has 18 questions. The frequent tab for this tag has 1 question:

- [glossaries package and footnote in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1633016/1595451)

There are 10 questions having [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) + [glossaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossaries). They are about handling glossaries using LaTex.

### Related

- [How do I create a glossary on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400736/1595451)
- [What to do with the [term] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400992/1595451)

Comment: Is either tag really needed?

Comment: @Braiam I think that is left to be determined...

Comment: Perhaps this should be a [tag-wiki request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-wiki) for [tag-disambiguation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation) rather than a [synonym-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request) at this point.

Comment: @bad_coder for me, tag should be _obvious_ what they are about, since people tend [not to read the description of the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256114/). Glossary and terminology are terms with meaning outside of programming, and "define this concept to me" isn't a very throughout questions that wouldn't be answered by several resources online already.

Comment: @Braiam Since we have a lot (>300)  questions having score >100  that use [tag:terminology]  and that the top users of this tag have score >750 I think that it's fair to say that we *need* it.

Comment: @Rubén nope, we _need_ it only when people actually answer questions with it. Not just people _asking_ questions. Tags are meant to serve answerers, not askers.

Comment: @Rubén btw, if it didn't exist, most of these would be answered by the other tags already included (which are more pointed towards answerers): language tags.

Comment: @Braiam By "top users" I was referring to top answerers... there are people answering questions having [tag:terminology]. There are >1.9k (~90%) questions that have at least one answer. By the way, what is the consensus to say that a tag is *needed*?

Answer (score 1):

**Glossary:**

- There are currently [3,699 post on SO with the word *"Glossary"*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=glossary).
- Of those [1,427 are questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=glossary+is%3Aquestion).
- Only [95 of those questions are tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary).

**Terminology:**

- There are currently [32,771 posts on SO with the word *"Terminology"*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=terminology).
- Of those [13,942 are questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=terminology+is%3Aquestion).
- Only [2,189 of those questions are tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

**Potential specialized uses of Glossary:**

1. [`Glossaries`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Using_glossaries) can refer to a LateX package. [Currently has 22 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blatex%5D+glossaries+is%3Aquestion).

2. [Glossary](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html401-20180327/types.html#h-6.12) can refer to a link type in basic HTML. [Currently has 2 tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+glossary).

3. [Glossary](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#create-glossary) is a part of the Google Cloud Translation API. I leave it to someone else to find a meaningful search.

4. [`.. glossary::`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#glossary) is a Python Sphinx directive. [Currently has 12 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+python-sphinx)

These were the 4 meaningful uses I found. I leave it to SME's that may care to look within each tag to quantify potential narrowing between uses of the term as a subject keyword or just a textual occurrence.

In any application Glossary is a specialized item, the very low number of specific subject occurrences can be used as an argument for burnination, or against it.

**A glossary isn't terminology:**

> Tl;Dr glossary is being used on questions about terms. We already have terminology for those questions. [glossary]

With only [95 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=Relevance&q=%5bglossary%5d%20is%3aquestion) the OP could have told us exactly how may are tagged incorrectly. The number of tag missuses, by its number, isn't alarming nor does it warrant a synonym based on that argument alone. (In those cases a re-tag is in order.)

There is no visible gain in making it a synonym. The merge would make the destination tag a larger bag-of-words and increase, instead of diminishing, entropy and ambiguity.

Turning an occasional misuse, into a systemic misnomer.

Comment: A word of advice "Tags should help to describe what the question is about, **not just what it contains**." People including a keyword in their questions isn't enough to say that it's about that.

Comment: @Braiam I consider [this tag-wiki a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/documentation/info) of use guidance.

Comment: Sadly [people don't read tag excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256114/)

Comment: Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63639197/how-to-document-websockets

Comment: @Braiam you don't have to remind me in the comments of what a tag-wiki should be because I already know. If you want to contribute an answer that adds to the specific problem raised in the question I'll be happy to consider it.

Comment: @Rubén You've noticed that a glossary and terminology aren't the same thing?

Comment: @Rubén don't take my answer the wrong way. It's meant as a contribution, not as a contradiction. Personally I think the tag has its place, precisely because it is small. Tags with few post attract even less posts. So whoever appreciates those specialty items is discouraged from posting interesting or rare use cases about them, because they would get buried under a mass of textual occurrences that aren't about the subject.