# Disambiguate [glossary]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Few days ago I posted [Make [glossary] a synonym of [terminology]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400747/1595451). So far the score is 2 (+8 / -6), there is only one answer and some comments that lead me to the conclusion that there is no concensus yet, it might take a long time to get it or might never be achieved...

*In the meatime*, what about disambiguate [glossary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary)? What could be the proper usage of this tag according to the SO scope?

The current tag excerpt is

> list of terms and definitions used in a larger document

There are 95 questions having [glossary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary)

The frequent tab for this tag returns 30 questions, none of these questions are about glossaries instead they are about the meaning of certain terms, i.e.,

- [What is a 'Closure'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36636/1595451) (also has [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology))
- [Abstraction VS Information Hiding VS Encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24626/1595451)

Top users

[glossary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary) Top answerers have 1-2 answers.

Last 30 days

In the last 30 days there was 0 anwswers and 0 questions.

Here are some highlight from some tags

- [python-sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+python-sphinx) × 12

  - This tag has >2K questions
  - [[glossary] [python-sphinx]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+python-sphinx)
  - Looking at the [Active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary%2Bpython-sphinx?tab=Active), there are 10 questions that were edited this year and also have [restructuredtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restructuredtext) . Of those, 7 were edited on Jun 4 and 2 after that by the same user. The edits were only to add [glossary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary) to these questions.
- [restructuredtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+restructuredtext) × 10

  - This tag has 1007 questions
  - As was mentioned above, these 10 questions having both tags also have [python-sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-sphinx) -> [[glossary][python-sphingx][restructuredtext]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+python-sphinx+restructuredtext)
- [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+language-agnostic) × 8

  - This tag has >8k questions
  - There are 7 open questions all of them ask for a term definition
- [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+terminology) × 3

  - This tag has >2k questions
  - On these 3 questions having both tags looks that [glossary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary) is redudant as the questions are askig for the meaning of a term (and that term is not "glossary")
- [definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+definition) × 3

  - This tag has >1K questions
  - One question is closed
  - The other 2 questions doesn't look to be properly tagged.
- [glossaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+glossaries) × 3

  - This tag has 17 questions
  - There 11 questions having [glossaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossaries) and [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex)
  - This might tag might look as the plural of [glossary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary), but it hasn't a tag excerpt/wiki and the use with LaTex apparently is to refer to the Glossaries LaTex package.

Other related tags that I not reviewed yet.

- [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+drupal) × 5
- [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+javascript) × 4
- [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+c%23) × 4
- [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+c%23) × 4
- [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 4
- [functional-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 4
- [drupal-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 4
- [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 4
- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 3
- [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 3
- [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 3
- [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 3
- [drupal-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 3
- [view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 3
- [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 3
- [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 3
- [computer-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 3
- [highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+) × 3
- [paradigms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary+paradigms) × 3

Related

- [What to do with the [term] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400992/1595451)