# What to do with the [term] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

The [term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term) tag excerpt/wiki were extracted from the Wikipedia disambiguation article for "term" which make this tag to look like a meta-tag. It has 335 questions and 19 watchers. The All time aswerers have posted only one answer. The All time askers, one have made 3 posts one have made 2 posts, all others have made only one post.

The top related tags (>20 questions) are

- [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term+wordpress) × 73

  - [[term] [wordpress] [taxonomy]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term+wordpress+taxonomy) × 33. We also have [taxonomy-terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taxonomy-terms) (Terms are usually associated to custom taxonomies in Wordpress)
- [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term+elasticsearch) × 43
- [taxonomy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term+taxonomy) × 42
- [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term+php) × 38

Other related tags are

- [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term+terminology) × 10
- [custom-taxonomy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term+custom-taxonomy) × 10

It's worthy to note that we have

- [glossary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossary) (List of terms and definitions used in a larger document)
- [glossaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glossaries) (no tag excerpt)
- [definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/definitions) (A generic tag for topics providing definitions.)

---

Tag excerpt

> May refer to: 1) Term (language) or Terminology, 2) Term (time), 3) Technical term, 4) Scientific terminology or 5) Telecom Enforcement Resource and Monitoring.

Tag wiki

> Full list from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term):
>
> **Term** may refer to:
>
> 1. Term (language) or terminology, a noun or compound word used in a
>    specific context: meaning. See also the Index of linguistics
>    articles
> 2. Term (time) a fixed period of time
> 3. Term (computers) or terminal emulator, a program that emulates a
>    video terminal
> 4. Term (architecture) or terminal form, a human head and bust that
>    continues as a square tapering pillar-like form
> 5. Term, Iran, a village in Mazandaran Province, Iran
> 6. Payment (or credit) terms, a part of an invoice; when you'll have to
>    pay and what discount you'll get by paying early. Like "2/10 net
>    30".
> 7. Technical term, part of the specialized vocabulary of a particular
>    field
> 8. Scientific terminology, terms used by scientists
> 9. Contractual term, a legally binding provision
> 10. Telecom Enforcement Resource and Monitoring, the vigilance and
>     monitoring wing of the Indian Department of Telecommunications

Comment: In practice [tag:glossaries] is used for a LaTeX package - although the tag wiki does not currently indicating that use. (Since you refer another tag, simply stating it doesn't have a tag-wiki makes things more difficult for the readers.)

Comment: @bad_coder [tag:glossaries] is used also on question that aren't related to [tag:latex]

Comment: @bad_coder We have [tex.se]. While it's OK that the sites scopes overlap someway, I think that people asking questions about LaTex should be warned of that site.