# Asking for wisdom, strategy and judgement?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, opinion-based

Like others, I'm an active consumer of Stack Overflow, and I'm 2+ decades into my technical career. I often need to make decisions with imprecise information. Occasionally I ask Stack Overflow.  These questions usually get rapidly closed for being vague or opinionated.

I see the endless posts about closed questions. Those 10k results are potentially from a lot of thoughtful posters. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed  And that's just people who know about meta.stackoverflow.

My technical questions are the software equivalent to "*I'm tired of orange juice, what's a good long-term option?*" or "*I can't get myself to exercise (or floss my teeth), what's a good way to do this more?*" Real problems that have obvious backstories and complexities to anyone that has some real life experience under their belt.

Is there a broader mindset thing going on here? Or is Stack Overflow really just for people who can't bother to read the manual, and have questions one step above homework.  Sure I use Stack Overflow to look up "how do I reverse an array in ruby?" when I want to save 50 seconds. But there are many interesting, more complex tasks that Stack Overflow shoots down.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what your question is here, if I am honest. Can you try to elaborate.

Comment: SO is *ideally* for long-lasting answers to questions about programming. Unfortunately, the posts that answerers get the most enjoyment out of answering tend to not be that. Philosophical/subjective questions about the technologies that exist today and where they lie on the scale of usefulness aren't long-lasting.

Comment: _Some_ of the questions you're asking about (not the "recommend me an alternative to X" ones) would be on topic at [softwareengineering.se].  That said, there are plenty of problems on-topic for Stack Overflow that aren't in the manual.  Of course, we _also_ allow the ones that are in the manual, because sometimes the manuals aren't easy to search.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for acknowledging that some deeper questions might interest folks, but I see your point.

Comment: see also: [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252777/839601)

Answer (score 16):

We're not here for the subjective.  We're here to answer the concrete technical programming questions you have.

If you want to entertain broader, more subjective questions which may not have a right or wrong answer, there are forums and subreddits out there which could entertain your perspective if you so desired.

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow's goal is to create a knowledge base that's very easy for Google to index.  For that purpose it wants questions with definitive factual answers.  Questions that would instead trigger long debates aren't wanted.

The questions your examples suggest you want to ask would be better taken to Reddit or some other internet forum.  Here they'll continue to be closed as unsuited for the site.